# SQL query, two tables, multiple items

Tags: mysql, sql

I wish to retrieve data from two tables with a twist, I need multiple values (prices from different dates) from the second table. The following works fine, but I am not much of a SQL jockey and I have a sneaking suspicion that there must be a better way than joining the second table twice. Is there?

```
SELECT A.date, A.symbol, A.Value, B.close, C.close
FROM Potential A 
LEFT JOIN Stock_Daily B ON A.symbol = B.symbol
LEFT JOIN Stock_Daily C ON A.symbol = C.symbol 
WHERE A.Date = "2015-08-05" AND B.date = "2015-08-05" AND C.date = "2015-08-04"
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So: MySQL or Microsoft SQL Server?

Comment: Joining twice two get values in one row is exactly the correct way to get multiple, distinct values.

Comment: @kittykittybangbang MySQL

Comment: Are you sure this is working fine?  You have a potential issue in your SQL statement - with all of your conditioning logic in the `WHERE` clause, you are turning your `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`, which can lead to incorrect results.  If you are truly wanting a `LEFT JOIN` here, move the `AND B.date = "2015-08-05" AND C.date = "2015-08-04"` bits to their respective `ON` clauses.

Comment: I am using MySQL, but the tag expert suggested adding sql-server so I did. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You might find this condition easier to work with: `WHERE A.Date = "2015-08-05" AND B.date = A.Date AND C.date = DATE_ADD(A.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perfectly fine to do it the way you're doing it, but to expand a bit more on the comment, there is a potential issue with your query.  Since you are doing a `LEFT JOIN` with the conditional logic in the `WHERE` clause for the joined table, it is effectively transforming the `LEFT JOIN` into an `INNER JOIN`.

Should there be any dates missing from the right-hand table to not satisfy an `INNER JOIN`, this will give you incorrect results.

I recommend changing the query to the following to avoid this:

```
SELECT A.date, A.symbol, A.Value, B.close, C.close
FROM Potential A 
LEFT JOIN Stock_Daily B ON A.symbol = B.symbol AND B.date = "2015-08-05"
LEFT JOIN Stock_Daily C ON A.symbol = C.symbol AND C.date = "2015-08-04"
WHERE A.Date = "2015-08-05" 
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I think that this should be the accepted answer as it is the simplest and most direct. However, I learned a lot from the answer provided @Mureinik and would have voted it up if my cred had been high enough.

Answer (score 0):

This double joining with a different condition on `B` and `C` is just fine. It may be a tad more elegant to use subqueries to make the query easier to read:

```
SELECT A.date, A.symbol, A.Value, B.close, C.close
FROM Potential A 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT close, date
           FROM   Stock_Daily 
           WHERE  date = "2015-08-05") B ON A.symbol = B.symbol
LEFT JOIN (SELECT close, date
           FROM   Stock_Daily 
           WHERE  date = "2015-08-05") C ON A.symbol = C.symbol 
WHERE A.Date = "2015-08-05"
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 20;
```

But ultimately, it's just a matter of taste - your query is just fine.

Comment: IMO, that's actually HARDER to read...but as you stated, it's a matter of taste.

Comment: I disagree that that is any harder. The benefit is that it's more "modular".

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the pivoting with `case` expressions and `group by`:

```
SELECT
    p.date, p.symbol,
    min(p.value) value, /* dummy aggregate */
    min(CASE WHEN s.Date = p.Date THEN s.close END) Close1,
    min(CASE WHEN s.Date = DATE_ADD(p.Date, INTERVAL 1 DAY THEN s.close END) Close2
FROM
    Potential p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Stock_Daily s
        ON  s.symbol = p.symbol AND
            (s.date = p.date or s.date = DATE_ADD(p.date, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY p.date, p.symbol
ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of the CASE statement in SQL queries. Thanks, that'll be VERY useful.

Comment: I left out the `ELSE null` which is implied though I would usually be explicit. Since it's new to you I wanted to add that note.